# fullPage.js One Page Scroll - can't scroll to footer after the last section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I'm trying to get to work the plugin fullPage.js (http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/).
But I have an issue with some part.

When I slidie section by section it works ok, but when I reach the last section and try to scroll to a footer which after this, it stucks. I can reach the footer only when I use a scrollbar.

Maybe, there's a way to reach the footer through the scroll?

Thanks a lot!

my code structure:

```
<body>
 <content>
  <section>1</section>
  <section>2</section>
  <section>3</section>
  ...
  </content>
 <footer>
  footer is here
 </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: We need some code to actually see if there's a problem in it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

fullpage.js won't allow you to scroll to something outside the fullpage.js wrapper unless you use `autoScrolling:false`, which it doesn't seem to be what you want.

How big is your footer? If it it small, why don't you just make use of `fp-auto-height` ?

- [Example online](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/autoHeight.html)
- [Documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#creating-smaller-sections)

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code I am not sure I can help but I can give you things to try on your own.

First: Do you want the footer to be fixed at bottom or scroll into view?

- If fixed you need to tell it that in the script:  `fixedElements: '#header, .footer',`
- If scroll is what you want try one of these: In the script use `normalScrollElements: '.footer',` OR try putting the footer in the last section element

After that I would need to see your code.

Comment: dreamweaver, Stefan Neuenschwander thank you for the answer! I use WP CMS, and I have WP code structure. I use sections only at the home page and I don't want to duplicate footer in the home page, because if I need edit some content I need to fix it in both places. fixedElements: '#header, .footer' and normalScrollElements: '.footer' - don't work. I'm going to edit my post and try to portray my structure. Thank you for help!